# getting error in terminal when add to firebase_auth in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

i get this error "Because firebase_auth depends on firebase_auth, version solving failed."
when i going to add flutter pub add firebase_auth. how to solve this?

Dependancies in pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
firebase_core: ^2.16.0

i want to solve this problem and add firebase_auth to my project